# "Virulent bacteria"

Tags: adjectives

I [read](http://healthland.time.com/2011/06/02/why-health-authorities-are-so-worried-about-europes-mutant-e-coli-outbreak/#ixzz1O8LxRbeD)

> Health officials were worried enough about an unusually **virulent** outbreak of food-borne illness from the E. coli **bacteria**,

This seems so wrong.

1. Is there a name for it? (mixed metaphors, for example)
2. Is it recommended?

Comment: Is it not an [oxymoron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron)?

Comment: Okay, my answer and the others look like we're talking about different things.  Can you clarify what seems wrong to you?

Comment: "[Virulent bacteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virulence#Virulent_bacteria)" seems to be a term in medicine, indicating ability to cause disease - perhaps related more to the figurative sense of "virulent" meaning "hostile" than to its origin from "virus".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oxymoron involves a direct opposition between the connotation of the noun and the denotation of the adjective, e.g. jumbo shrimp. This is not that, since "virulent" is not derived from the modern sense of "virus." According the OED, virulence refers to the contagiousness of a disease from as far back the late 16th century. While virus was used to describe pathogenic factors at least that far back, the modern sense of a virus as a factor distinct from bacteria did not occur until 1900.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like an oxymoron (using contradictory terms), but it's not technically one. Moreover, *bacteria* and *virulent* are not contradictory, if you think about it in terms of the time line. The terms introduced, with their shifts in meaning, are:

- 14th century: *virus* means “poisonous substance” (from the Latin *virus*) and *virulent* means “full of poisonous substance” (from the Latin *virulentus*, “full of poison”)
- 16th century: *virulent* acquires its meaning of “violent, spiteful”.
- 1728: first recorded use of *virus* to mean “pathogen agent”.
- later, it becomes formally defined as “infectious agent that can replicate only inside the living cells of organisms”, as opposed to bacteria.

---

<sup>All the above thanks to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Virulence is defined as

> vir·u·lence definition
>   Pronunciation:  /ˈvir-(y)ə-lən(t)s/ 
>   Function: n 
>   :  the quality or state of being virulent: as 
>   a :  relative severity and malignancy the virulence  of a disease> 
>   b :  the relative capacity of a pathogen to overcome body defenses compare INFECTIVITY 
>   Merriam-Webster's Medical Dictionary, © 2007 Merriam-Webster, Inc.

It's not specific to viruses, but can be used for any disease causing agent. The word virus was used for centuries before we were able to actually identify the things we presently call viruses and referred to poison/venom.

Answer (score 2):

In the biomedical domain, *virulence* is used to describe *how* infectious a disease is, so it is appropriate to say that one strain of bacteria is more virulent than another. I'll see if I can find a reference for this usage for you.

It sounds odd to me to say a "virulent outbreak," but the definition of [virulent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/virulent) and the definition of [outbreak](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outbreak) don't actually overlap, so it's not redundant.  It ought to mean a surprising, infectious burst, which I think is the intended use here.

Comment: I think the objection was that virulent implied virus which is different to a bacteria

Comment: Well, I'm gathering that's what everyone but me thinks, because virulent doesn't imply virus.  But I wasn't sure, so that's why I asked for clarification.  If I'm way off, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: you (and all the others) are correct it doesn't. But since most people wouldn't see the difference between virus/bacteria anyway and those that would also know the origins of virulent.

Answer (score 0):

*Virulent*, when referring to a pathogen, means "highly infective."

It is perfectly fine to speak of "virulent bacteria," as "highly infective" refers to how easily (or fast) the infection spreads out.